# How to allow localhost for Twitter api?

Tags: javascript, twitter, firebase

I'm running my single page app on localhost and I am able to get an access token for my twitter account (using Firebase), but when I attempt to perform a get to this resource it fails with following failure...

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]`

Error message (in the Chrome Console):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?access_token=[MY_ACCESS_TOKEN]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've looked around and I'm starting to question whether doing this is possible without a proxy...

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @Kato, I believe that's something that is set on the server. I have no server (I'm using a github page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your request to twitter API is sent from your browser. As far as I know, you can't make this work.

You should change your code to have it sent by your server (the localhost one), acting as a proxy.

Comment: You could do JSONP requests to allow them to work cross-origin.

Comment: @AndrewLee Twitter API 1.1 does not support JSONP, cf. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10644?page=1

Comment: @Mehdi What I don’t understand, is how I am able to make Twitter API requests using the Postman desktop app, but I cannot make a request via the browser. What is Postman doing that allows it, to bypass CORS? I do know that I am able to make Twitter API requests locally, within an Electron Angular app, but I cannot make a request from an Angular app, via localhost:4200 Maybe the Postman desktop app is an Electron app?